# Groovy pipeline in Jenkins duplicate class definition for name: "lib/lib"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

We have Jenkins with a couple of plugins. Including the Groovy-Pipeline plugin. Problem is that Jenkins sometime does not run and we get the message:

```
Sep 12, 2017 3:33:16 PM hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression evaluate
WARNING: Caught exception evaluating: job.buildHealthReports in /. Reason: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.PropertyExecutor.execute(PropertyExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelGetterImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:314)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsGroovyShell$CleanGroovyClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "lib/lib"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

When I disable the plugin the error goes away.
Notable is that it seems to handle around "job.buildHealthReports" and that the problem is "lib/lib". I assume some duplicate library loading...

Installed plugins:

> Enabled        Name  ↓     Version         Previously installed version
>   Pinned         Uninstall       Allure Jenkins Plugin This plugin
>   integrates Allure reporting tool into Jenkins.
>     2.22
>              AnsiColor Adds ANSI coloring to the Console Output
>     0.5.2
>              Ant Plugin Adds Apache Ant support to Jenkins
>     1.7 
>              Authentication Tokens API Plugin This plugin provides an API for converting credentials into authentication tokens in Jenkins.
>     1.3              Autofavorite for Blue Ocean Automatically favorites multibranch pipeline jobs when user is the author
>     1.0.0
>              Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin Allows to use Bitbucket Cloud as a source for multi-branch projects. It also provides the required
>   connectors for Bitbucket Cloud Team Folder (also known as repositories
>   auto-discovering).
>     2.2.3                Bitbucket Pipeline for Blue Ocean BlueOcean Bitbucket pipeline creator
>     1.2.0
>              Blue Ocean BlueOcean Aggregator
>     1.2.0
>              Blue Ocean Pipeline Editor The Blue Ocean Pipeline Editor is the simplest way for anyone wanting to get started with creating Pipelines
>   in Jenkins
>     1.2.0
>              bouncycastle API Plugin This plugin provides an stable API to Bouncy Castle related tasks.
>     2.16.2
>              Branch API Plugin This plugin provides an API for multiple branch based projects.
>     2.0.11
>              Build Monitor View Provides a highly visible view of the status of selected Jenkins jobs. It easily accommodates different computer
>   screen sizes and is ideal as an Extreme Feedback Device to be
>   displayed on a screen on your office wall.
>     1.12+build.201704111018 
>              Common API for Blue Ocean This plugin is a part of Blue Ocean UI
>     1.2.0
>              Config API for Blue Ocean BlueOcean Analytics Tools plugin
>     1.2.0
>              Config File Provider Plugin Ability to provide configuration files (e.g. settings.xml for maven, XML, groovy, custom files,...)
>   loaded through the UI which will be copied to the job workspace.
>     2.16.3               Credentials Binding Plugin Allows credentials to be bound to environment variables for use from miscellaneous build steps.
>     1.13
>              Credentials Plugin This plugin allows you to store credentials in Jenkins.
>     2.1.15
>              Cucumber json test reporting. This plugin understands cucumber json files and converts them to Jenkins TestCase so they can be seen
>   in the standard test reports.
>     0.9.7                Cucumber reports This project provides pretty html reports for Cucumber. It works by generating html from the cucumber json
>   report formatter. Can be used anywhere a json report is generated
>   (Java, Ruby, JavaScript and other implementations).
>     3.10.1
>              Dashboard for Blue Ocean Blue Ocean Dashboard
>     1.2.0
>              Display URL API Provides the DisplayURLProvider extension point to provide alternate URLs for use in notifications
>     2.0 
>              Display URL for Blue Ocean This plugin generates BlueOcean specific URLs for the Display URL plugin.
>     2.1.0
>              Docker Commons Plugin Provides the common shared functionality for various Docker-related plugins.
>     1.8 
>              Docker Pipeline Build and use Docker containers from pipelines.
>     1.12
>              Durable Task Plugin Library offering an extension point for processes which can run outside of Jenkins yet be monitored.
>     1.14
>              Events API for Blue Ocean Blue Ocean Events
>     1.2.0
>              External Monitor Job Type Plugin Adds the ability to monitor the result of externally executed jobs
>     1.7              Favorite This plugin allows users to favorite a job.
>     2.3.0
>              Folders Plugin This plugin allows users to create "folders" to organize jobs. Users can define custom taxonomies (like by project
>   type, organization type etc). Folders are nestable and you can define
>   views within folders. Maintained by CloudBees, Inc.
>     6.1.2
>              Git client plugin Utility plugin for Git support in Jenkins
>     2.5.0
>              Git Pipeline for Blue Ocean BlueOcean Git SCM pipeline creator
>     1.2.0
>              Git plugin This plugin integrates Git with Jenkins.
>     3.5.1
>              GIT server Plugin Allows Jenkins to act as a Git server.
>     1.7              GitHub API Plugin This plugin provides GitHub API for other plugins.
>     1.86
>              GitHub Branch Source Plugin Multibranch projects and organization folders from GitHub. Maintained by CloudBees, Inc.
>     2.2.3
>              GitHub Organization Folder Plugin The functionality that was provided by this plugin has been moved to the GitHub Branch Source
>   plugin. You can safely delete this plugin once there are no plugins
>   that depend on this plugin installed.
>     1.6              GitHub Pipeline for Blue Ocean BlueOcean GitHub organization pipeline creator
>     1.2.0
>              GitHub plugin This plugin integrates GitHub to Jenkins.
>     1.28.0
>              Green Balls Because green is better than blue! For color blind support configure user property.
>     1.15                 Hidden Parameter plugin
>     0.0.4                HipChat Plugin This plugin is a HipChat notifier that can publish build status to HipChat rooms.
>     2.1.1                HTML Publisher plugin This plugin publishes HTML reports.
>     1.14                 i18n for Blue Ocean Blue Ocean Internationalization (i18n) Plugin. This plugin is a part of the Blue Ocean Plugin set.
>     1.2.0
>              Icon Shim Plugin Allows plugins make full use of the  layout tag when running on newer versions of Jenkins, while still
>   being compatible with older versions.
>     2.0.3                Jackson 2 API Plugin This plugin exposes the Jackson 2 JSON APIs to other Jenkins plugins.
>     2.7.3                Javadoc Plugin
>     1.4              JavaScript GUI Lib: ACE Editor bundle plugin JavaScript GUI Lib: ACE Editor bundle plugin.
>     1.1              JavaScript GUI Lib: Handlebars bundle plugin JavaScript GUI Lib: Handlebars bundle plugin.
>     1.1.1                JavaScript GUI Lib: jQuery bundles (jQuery and jQuery UI) plugin JavaScript GUI Lib: jQuery bundles (jQuery and jQuery UI)
>   plugin.
>     1.2.1                JavaScript GUI Lib: Moment.js bundle plugin JavaScript GUI Lib: Moment.js bundle plugin.
>     1.1.1                JIRA plugin This plugin integrates Jenkins to Atlassian JIRA.
>     2.4.2                jQuery plugin This allows other plugins to use jQuery in UI.
>     1.11.2-0                 JUnit Plugin Allows JUnit-format test results to be published.
>     1.21
>              JWT for Blue Ocean BlueOcean JWT plugin: Enables JWT based BlueOcean API authentication
>     1.2.0
>              Kubernetes plugin Jenkins plugin to run dynamic slaves in a Kubernetes/Docker environment
>     1.0 
>              LDAP Plugin Adds LDAP authentication to Jenkins
>     1.16
>              Mailer Plugin This plugin allows you to configure email notifications for build results
>     1.20
>              Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin Offers matrix-based security authorization strategies (global and per-project).
>     1.7 
>              Matrix Project Plugin Multi-configuration (matrix) project type.
>     1.11
>              Maven Integration plugin This plug-in provides, for better and for worse, a deep integration of Jenkins and Maven: Automatic triggers
>   between projects depending on SNAPSHOTs, automated configuration of
>   various Jenkins publishers (Junit, ...).
>     2.17
>              Maven Release Plug-in Plug-in A plug-in that enables you to perform releases using the maven-release-plugin from Jenkins.
>     0.14.0               Mercurial plugin This plugin integrates Mercurial SCM with Hudson. It includes repository browsing support for hg
>   serve/hgweb, Google Code, Bitbucket, FishEye, KilnHG and RhodeCode.
>   Features include guaranteed clean builds, named branch support, module
>   lists, Mercurial tool installation, and automatic caching.
>     2.1              Metrics Plugin This plugin exposes the Metrics API to Jenkins plugins.
>     3.1.2.10
>              NodeJS Plugin NodeJS Plugin executes NodeJS script as a build step.
>     1.2.4
>              OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin Uses the OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer to allow safe-seeming HTML markup to be entered in project
>   descriptions and the like.
>     1.5              PAM Authentication plugin Adds Unix Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) support to Jenkins
>     1.3              Personalization for Blue Ocean Blue Ocean Personalization
>     1.2.0
>              Pipeline A suite of plugins that lets you orchestrate automation, simple or complex. See Pipeline as Code with Jenkins for more details.
>     2.5 
>              Pipeline Graph Analysis Plugin Provides a REST API to access pipeline and pipeline run data.
>     1.5 
>              Pipeline implementation for Blue Ocean This plugin is a part of BlueOcean Plugin
>     1.2.0
>              Pipeline SCM API for Blue Ocean This plugin is a part of BlueOcean Plugin
>     1.2.0
>              Pipeline Utility Steps Utility steps for pipeline jobs.
>     1.4.0
>              Pipeline: API Plugin that defines Pipeline API.
>     2.20
>              Pipeline: Basic Steps Commonly used steps for Pipelines.
>     2.6 
>              Pipeline: Build Step Adds the Pipeline step build to trigger builds of other jobs.
>     2.5.1
>              Pipeline: Declarative Agent API Replaced by Pipeline: Declarative Extension Points API plugin.
>     1.1.1
>              Pipeline: Declarative Extension Points API APIs for extension points used in Declarative Pipelines.
>     1.1.9
>              Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries Allows Pipeline Grrovy libraries to be loaded on the fly from GitHub.
>     1.0              Pipeline: Groovy Pipeline execution engine based on continuation passing style transformation of Groovy scripts.
>     2.40
>              Pipeline: Input Step Adds the Pipeline step input to wait for human input or approval.
>     2.8 
>              Pipeline: Job Defines a new job type for pipelines and provides their generic user interface.
>     2.11.2
>              Pipeline: Milestone Step Plugin that provides the milestone step
>     1.3.1
>              Pipeline: Model API Model API for Declarative Pipeline.
>     1.1.9
>              Pipeline: Model Definition An opinionated, declarative Pipeline.
>     1.1.9
>              Pipeline: Multibranch Enhances Pipeline plugin to handle branches better by automatically grouping builds from different branches.
>     2.16
>              Pipeline: Nodes and Processes Pipeline steps locking agents and workspaces, and running external processes that may survive a Jenkins
>   restart or slave reconnection.
>     2.15
>              Pipeline: REST API Plugin Provides a REST API to access pipeline and pipeline run data.
>     2.9 
>              Pipeline: SCM Step Adds a Pipeline step to check out or update working sources from various SCMs (version control).
>     2.5 
>              Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries Shared libraries for Pipeline scripts.
>     2.8 
>              Pipeline: Stage Step Adds the Pipeline step stage to delineate portions of a build.
>     2.2              Pipeline: Stage Tags Metadata Library plugin for Pipeline stage tag metadata.
>     1.1.9
>              Pipeline: Stage View Plugin Pipeline Stage View Plugin.
>     2.9 
>              Pipeline: Step API API for asynchronous build step primitive.
>     2.12
>              Pipeline: Supporting APIs Common utility implementations to build Pipeline Plugin
>     2.14
>              Plain Credentials Plugin Allows use of plain strings and files as credentials.
>     1.4              Pub-Sub "light" Bus A simple Publish-Subscribe light-weight event bus for Jenkins
>     1.12
>              Publish Over SSH Send build artifacts over SSH
>     1.17                 Resource Disposer Plugin Dispose resources asynchronously. Utility plugin for resources that require more retries or take a long
>   time to delete.
>     0.7 
>              REST API for Blue Ocean This plugin is a part of Blue Ocean UI
>     1.2.0
>              REST Implementation for Blue Ocean This plugin is a part of Blue Ocean UI
>     1.2.0
>              SCM API Plugin This plugin provides a new enhanced API for interacting with SCM systems.
>     2.2.1
>              Script Security Plugin Allows Jenkins administrators to control what in-process scripts can be run by less-privileged users.
>     1.34
>              Serenity plugin This plugin publishes Serenity reports which are code coverage, complexity and stability project metrics.
>     1.2              Server Sent Events (SSE) Gateway Plugin Server Sent Events (SSE) Gateway.
>     1.15                 Shelve Project Plugin This plugin lets you shelve projects so that they can easily be resurrected.
>     1.5              SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins This plugin allows an easy integration of SonarQube, the open source platform for Continuous
>   Inspection of code quality.
>     2.6.1
>              SSH Credentials Plugin Allows storage of SSH credentials in Jenkins
>     1.13                 Structs Plugin Library plugin for DSL plugins that need names for Jenkins objects.
>     1.10
>              Token Macro Plugin This plug-in adds reusable macro expansion capability for other plug-ins to use.
>     2.3 
>              Variant Plugin This user-invisible library plugin allows other multi-modal plugins to behave differently depending on where they run.
>     1.1              Web for Blue Ocean Blue Ocean core
>     1.2.0
>              Windows Slaves Plugin Allows you to connect to Windows machines and start slave agents on them.
>     1.3.1
>              Workspace Cleanup Plugin This plugin deletes the project workspace after a build is finished.
>     0.34

Any ideas??? I don't even have a clue on where to search for a solution so any help would be welcome.

Thanks,
Milo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some crashed pipelines that did not have any status in the overview screen. After deleting the build instances from those jobs (..//build/...) the error went away. Wrong build can be seen by that there are no symlinks to the job.

You'll understand when you go to the corresponding folders :)

Cleanup script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export BASEFOLDER="/data/jenkins/volumes/tools/web/jobs/"

cd $BASEFOLDER
for folder in */; do
  echo "Checking '$folder'..."
  cd "${folder}builds" 2>/dev/null || continue
  export HIGHEST=`ls | grep -o '[0-9]*' | sort -nr | head -n 1`
  echo "   Found $HIGHEST. Checking symlink..."
  if [ $(find . -maxdepth 1 -lname $HIGHEST | wc -l) -eq 0 ] && [ "$HIGHEST" != "" ]; then
    echo "      *******************************************"
    echo "      Missing. Running the command below to fix this:"
    echo "        rm -rf \"`pwd`/$HIGHEST\""
    echo "      *******************************************"
    rm -rf \"`pwd`/$HIGHEST\"
  fi
  cd $BASEFOLDER
done
```